# How to find out if a specific digit is in the middle of an integer value?

Tags: python, for-loop, integer

Homework question is asking me to write a program that would output True if an integer is odd and has the number "0" in the middle of it. I figured out how to get it to print True if a number is odd but can't figure out how to detect if the number 0 is in the middle.

I've figured out the first condition which would be detecting if it's odd.

```
input:
  def is_cyclops(n):
    if len(str (n)) % 2 != 0:
      return True
    return False
  print (is_cyclops(11011))
output:
True
```

I want to know how to get the code to detect the number 0 in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide a response in the form of an algorithm:

- Convert the number to a string
- Detect whether the string has an even or odd number of characters (because even numbered strings don't have a single "middle" character)
- Look at the middle character which is character # (len(str)/2)-0.5
- That's your middle character

Comment: Since ((len(n)/2)-0.5) is supposed to find the middle character, wouldnt the logical thing to do would be making an if statement where it would return True if ((len(n)/2)-0.5) == 0? for some reason I get an "None" returned.

Comment: @FarhanIqbal That's an alternative way of handling what my second bulletpoint item covers.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for an input n.

```
n = str(n)
if(len(n)%2==0): #Checks if even
    if(n[len(n)/2]==0): #Checks for presence of 0
        return True
else:
    if(n[len(n+1)/2]==0): #Checks for presence of 0
        return True
```

Comment: Hey Vishwan, Thank you for the reply but for some reason whenever I try to run the code it gives me an error which says:


 if(n[len(n+1)/2]==0): (len(str)/2)-0.5) == 0):TypeError: object of type 'int' ha s no len()s no len()